# How to plot a graph from multiple origins?

Tags: gnuplot

The image below is an example that I need to reproduce and I do not know where to start.

[image: output]

Could someone advise me? I have a certain familiarity with **gnuplot**. How do I create multiple origins?

Comment: You’ve tagged both gnuplot and Octave. Please pick one. The answers for the two packages will be wildly different and incompatible.

Comment: it also depends very much on how your datafile(s) look like. Please post a few lines of the data that we get an idea about the data structure. Otherwise it will be difficult to help.

Comment: I want gnuplot.

Comment: Each profile I have is the value of X and Y ... where Y is the height of the geometry and X is the velocity.

Comment: What exactly you need to reproduce from the example? Is it the actual lines in each panel or just the layout (3 stacked panels with similar x and y ranges)?

Comment: are you still interested in an answer? The profiles with X and Y value, are they from several files? Or one single file? Many columns? Or two columns and many blocks separated by one or several empty lines? Please describe the structure of your input data.

Comment: @MarceloJoão Does the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your data structure it is difficult to make any suitable suggestions.
Since there seems to be no interest of the OP for an answer anymore, I will make a suggestion for others.
And since no data is given, I will assume something.

The example data contains several profiles separated by two empty columns.
Here the y-values (z-values in OP's graph) are in column 1 (range 0 to 2), and the x-values (x-values in OP's graph) are in column 2 (range 0 to 1).

You have a conditional offset and scaling.
So, then simply implement this for your x,y data using the ternary operator, check `help ternary`.

- draw the rectangle and overwrite the ytic labels 1 -->0 and 3 --> 2
- the pseudocolumn -2, i.e. the zero-based data(sub)block number (check `pseudocolumns`), is assigned to `x0` which is used as x-offset.
- if `x0<=0` scale your y-values by 1 otherwise 1.5, and offset your values by 1 or 0, respectively.

**Script:**

```
### conditional offsets and scaling
reset session

# create some test data
set samples 50
set table $Data
    f(x,a) = a*(-(x-1)**2+1) + (rand(0)*0.2-0.1)*x*(x-2)
    do for [i=-3:15] {
        plot [0:2] '+' u 1:(f($1,(i+4)/20.))   w table
        plot '+' u ("") every ::0::2 w table
    }
unset table

set obj 1 rect from first -3, first 0 to first 0, first 1  fc "black" fs pattern 7

yScale(x)  = x<=0 ? 1 : 1.5
yOffset(x) = x<=0 ? 1 : 0

set xrange[-3:16]
set xtic 5 out add ("" -2)     # remove xtic at -2
set mxtics 5
set yrange[0:3]
set ytic 1 out add ("" 0, "0" 1, "" 2, "2" 3)  # overwrite y-tics
set mytic 2
set key noautotitle
set grid x,mx ls 1 lc "black"

plot $Data u (x0=column(-2)-3, $2+x0):($1*yScale(x0)+yOffset(x0)):-2 w l lc var
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]